# How do I fit directional variogram on gridded data, and for a given azimuth return the estimate range?

Tags: python, statistics, gis, geor, geostatistics

I have a digital elevation model of topographical features. My overall objective is to make a predictive model by regressing on the range of a directional variogram for a given azimuth. Are there any good python libraries which can accommodate this for gridded data?